# CORS error when try to display layer from remote geoserver

Tags: geoserver, cors, openlayers

I am following [this tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html) in order to add vector tiles using geoserver and OL3.
I am using some layer from a remote geoserver which I have access:

```
var layer = 'myworkspace:arm_trs_roads_osm';
var projection_epsg_no = '4326';
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
  style:style_simple,
  source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
    tilePixelRatio: 1, // oversampling when > 1
    tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 19}),
    format: new ol.format.MVT(),
    url: 'http://ogcserver.gis.wfp.org/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + layer +
        '@EPSG%3A'+projection_epsg_no+'@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf',
    crossOrigin: null
  })
})
```

When I try to display the layer on the map I get the well known CORS error:

```
Failed to load http://ogcserver.gis.wfp.org/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/my_workspace:arm_trs_roads_osm@EPSG%3A4326@pbf/3/0/4.pbf: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://vagrant-test.local.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

I am not sure how to solve this issue. I found this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113693/openlayers-3-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows) which says to enable CORS in the tomcat level. But it also says that this feature is available after tomcat 7.0.41 (I have 7.0.39; not possible to upgrade currently).

I have also enabled JSONP in my geoserver config files. But still I get the same error. Which other alternative do I have?

Comment: @Ian Turton that answer is not really helping as I explain above. I actually have already mentioned the URL you shared.

Comment: but it is the same question so try those answers, upvote the question, offer a bounty or edit your question to show why it is materially different.