# OSM:Redirect from 'https:' to 'https:' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

I'm using OSM Standard base layer with Openlayer V4.1 API. While accessing OSM getting Exception:

> Access to Image at
>   'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/18/113126/107324.png' from origin
>   'http://localhost:9040' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9040' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I also tried with and Without crossOrigin null.
The code is:

```
map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM(),
          opacity: 0.7,
          crossOrigin:null
        })
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: [19412406.33, -5050500.21],
        zoom: 5
      })
    });
  });
```

Any help to solve the issue?

Comment: Could you please tell me if it's duplicate then where i will enable CORS  or put jar files etc. for OpenStreetMap.Because that duplicate refrence link question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113693/openlayers-3-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows is relate to GeoServer CORS Issue.