# GeoServer returns 401 unauthorized when requesting data via openlayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, php

When using the line `crossOrigin: 'anonymous',`, it returns 401 unauthorized response.

When commenting out that line it works, but I have to be log in to the GeoServer.

**Update**:
I have changed the Request URL to the below format. Now i get a Deprecation message as shown in the yellow border at the bottom, only in chrome. In Firefox it works.

`var geoURL = "//username:password@81.4.../geoserver/web/wms";`

```
wmsSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
  url: geoURL,
  params: {
    'LAYERS': "web:streets" , 'TILED': true
  },
  serverType: 'geoserver',
  //crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
});
```

When accessing that url i get:

> [Deprecation] Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g. `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856 for more details.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113693/openlayers-3-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows

Comment: Docs on Geoserver site: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/auth/owsrest.html

Comment: @IanTurton No it's not. I am using Apache Tomcat, not jetty

Comment: look at the 2nd link

Comment: I have updated my question.